# Setting UITableView's accessory view to a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to set the accessory view of a UITableView to a UILabel. I have tried looking around the Internet for an answer but could not find anything. Here is what I do:

```
let listCountLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
    label.text = "1"
    label.layer.borderWidth = 2
    label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    label.textColor = .lightGray
    label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.height / 2
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 14)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
}()


//Add to Subview
view.addSubview(listCountLabel)


cell.accessoryView = listCountLabel
```

Comment: Do you just want to have a grey label on the right? Ty setting the table view's style to `.value1` instead of creating your own label.

Comment: @Sweeper, Ok I’ll give it a try.

Comment: Or, you could also have a custom `UITableViewCell` instead of adding it to the `accessoryView`

Comment: @VidyaMurthy I tried doing that, I didn’t know how to use a class to display information in my table view so I couldn’t figure it out. Do you know how to do this

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to call view.addSubView(). Just call listCountLabel.sizeToFit() before inserting it into cell.accessoryView.

```
listCountLabel.sizeToFit() 
cell.accessoryView = listCountLabel
```